# Get message from http response (javax.ws.rs.core.Response)

Tags: java, json, http, response

I have a Response object (javax.ws.rs.core.Response) and I need to print the message in it. I tried this way (resp is the Response object):

```
String msg = resp.readEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(msg);
```

But it prints a json with 3 fields: timestamp,message and details.
So I create a JsonResponse class defined as below:

```
public class JsonResponse {
    private String timestamp;
    private String message;
    private String details;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

And I print the message this way:

```
String msg = resp.readEntity(JsonResponse.class).getMessage();
System.out.println(msg);
```

This works fine but I think there's a better way to achieve this, probably without creating the JsonResponse class. Am I wrong?
Moreover, I think my code strongly depens from the structure with timestamp,message and details fields and if readEntity get some different it will fail parsing to JsonResponse class.

Comment: you are in right approach you need that `Response` class, or else you can use `Map` also

Comment: what about JsonResponse attributes? Will readEntity always get the json with that 3 fields? Now i'm using a server mock with springboot but will the "real" server provide  the same fields?